# How to find specific variables that cause vectors to be linearly independent / dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

The vectors

$v= \begin{bmatrix}
5\\
2\\
7\\
\end{bmatrix}, u = \begin{bmatrix}
4\\
4\\
13+k\\
\end{bmatrix}, \text{and } w = \begin{bmatrix}
-4\\
-2\\
-6\\
\end{bmatrix} $

are linearly independent if and only if $k \neq$ what?

How exactly can I go about solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Fly by Night mentioned, these vectors will be linearly dependent if and only if $$\det \begin{pmatrix}
5 & 4 & -4\\
2 & 4 & -2\\
7 & 13+k & -6
\end{pmatrix} = 0.$$

\begin{align*}
\det \begin{pmatrix}
5 & 4 & -4\\
2 & 4 & -2\\
7 & 13+k & -6
\end{pmatrix} &= 5[(4)(-6) - (13+k)(-2)] - 4[(2)(-6) - (7)(-2)] + (-4)[(2)(13+k)-(7)(4)] \\
&=2k+10
\end{align*}

Therefore the vectors will be linearly dependent if and only if $$ 2k+10 = 0.$$

Comment: oh I see now. So it will be linearly dependent $IFF$ det(A) is $0$ and it will be linearly independent $IFF$ the det(A) is $\ne 0$!

Comment: @Shammy Determinants are only defined for square matrices however.  This technique only works to check if $n$ vectors from $\Bbb R^n$ are linearly independent.  It will not check to see if $k$ vectors from $\Bbb R^n$ with $k<n$ are linearly independent.

Comment: As JMoravitz notes, it was important that we had $3$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so that the matrix was square. The determinant of a $n\times n$ matrix being not zero is equivalent to its rank being $n$.

If we had $k$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $k<n$ then you could still form a matrix with them as the columns, then row reduce to compute the rank. The rank of this matrix will be $k$ if and only if the vectors are linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

If you don't want to use the determinant you can write

$$l_1{\bf v} + l_2{\bf u} + l_3{\bf w} + l_4{\bf [0,0,1]^T = 0}, (\text{where   } l_4/l_2 = k)$$

This will be an overdetermined equation system and it will have a least-squares solution:

$$\min_{\forall l_k} \|l_1{\bf v} + l_2{\bf u} + l_3{\bf w} + l_4{\bf [0,0,1]^T\|_2 }$$

when $l_4/l_2 = k$ gives a perfect fit.

Comment: We haven't learned anything about least-squares.

Comment: Okay, then you will have something to look back to once you do.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If you have three vectors in three dimensions, then they are linearly dependent if and only if the determinant, of the 3-by-3 matrix whose columns (or rows) are your vectors, is zero.

(The determinant gives the volume of the [parallelepiped](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Parallelepiped.html) spanned by its columns (or rows)).

In general, if you have a set of $n$ vectors in $n$-dimensional space, they are linearly dependent if and only if the determinant, of the $n$-by-$n$ matrix whose columns (or rows) are your $n$ vectors, is zero.

Comment: Oh so I need to find the determinant. Ok one sec.